Files and folders on shared drive created on Linux are not visible in Windows (dual-boot)
I have a dual-boot with Linux (Manjaro) and Windows installed on two separate SSDs, plus I have a shared ex-fat HDD which contains documents and the like.
Problem is, very often, when I'm on Linux and I create or copy a file or folder on the HDD, then I cannot see it from Windows. If I switch back to Linux the file is still there. Sometimes it seems that it becomes visible also on Windows if I create a new file in the same location with touch for example, but I'm not sure about this.
The opposite works correctly, i.e. if I create a file from Windows, I can see it from Linux too.
Any idea why this happens?

Any idea why this happens? Yes, it's a consequence of Windows Fast Startup "feature". When dual-booting disabling the aforementioned "feature" is a must.

Also, MS Windows does not always work well with Linux writes to certain file systems. Try using a device formatted FAT32, such as a USB flash drive, as a test, to se if Linux-written files are shown in Windows.

@DrMoishePippik In the context of Windows-Linux dual-boot, provided Fast Startup is disabled, it works perfectly in NTFS, exFAT or any other natively supported filesystem in Windows.

@ChanganAuto I had disabled Fast Boot from BIOS but not Fast Startup in Windows. I'll try disabling that as well. Thanks.

The former is optional in every sense of the work but better to have it disabled at least immediately prior to an installation in order to have a more accurate hardware detection/initialization. The latter is a must when dual-booting precisely because the issue you notice and a few others and also recommended to be off in general even with only Windows.
